# How to change the diagonal rotation of a x-axis label on chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I am trying to figure out how change the rotation of dates on the x-axis of my chart.  See below the image.  I have examples of how to do it, but they don't match well as I have twin y axis's.  Can you help change the rotation of the dates?

Here is my code:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
t = df['date']
s1 = df['msft']

ax1.plot(t, s1, 'b-')
ax1.set_xlabel('Dates')
ax1.legend(loc=0)
ax1.grid()

# Make the y-axis label, ticks and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('Price', color='b')
ax1.tick_params('y', colors='b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
s2 = df['amzn']
ax2.plot(t, s2, 'r-')
ax2.set_ylabel('amzn', color='r')
ax2.tick_params('date', colors='r')
ax2.legend(loc=0)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: May be `plt.xticks(rotation=90)`?

Comment: Or, `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()`

Comment: Those are not working, Do you have other ideas?

Comment: ax1.set_xticklabels(t, rotation=45), I added this line and got the dates to be at a 45 degree angle.

Answer (score 0):

I added  `ax1.set_xticklabels(t, rotation=45)`, this line got the dates to be at a 45 degree angle. –

[image]